# Android Notification is not working

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I am following a code sample somewhere from internet in which i want to start a activity when click on notification. but when i click on show notification button it gives error..
Here is my notification code.

```
    public void showNotification(){

                // define sound URI, the sound to be played when there's a notification
                Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);        

                // intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions     
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BusinessDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", 1);

                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

                // this is it, we'll build the notification!
                // in the addAction method, if you don't want any icon, just set the first param to 0
                Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("New Post!")
                    .setContentText("Here's an awesome update for you!")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setSound(soundUri)
//                  .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "View", pIntent)
//                  .addAction(0, "Remind", pIntent)
                    .build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotification.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                // If you want to hide the notification after it was selected, do the code below
                // myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);

            }
```

Here is my logcat.

```
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.build
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.faisalahsan.discountcloud.MainActivity.showNotification(MainActivity.java:130)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.faisalahsan.discountcloud.MainActivity.onMenuItemSelected(MainActivity.java:147)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:950)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:490)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:108)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3519)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14140)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
06-28 23:32:29.150: E/AndroidRuntime(30461):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.build() was introduced in API level 16. Use "getNotification()".

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use similar code in older Android versions, you can use the `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` class, which is part of the compatibility library.

```
Notification mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Post!")
    .setContentText("Here's an awesome update for you!")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setSound(soundUri)
//  .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "View", pIntent)
//  .addAction(0, "Remind", pIntent)
    .build();
```

This would work in Android versions as old as API level 4.